# VMware Hypervisor version 4.1

Tags: vmware-esxi

When browsing the datastore on an ESXi server I have noticed that some of the .vmdk files will have a -flat.vmdk.  Just wondering why that is.  I have tried converting a running machine using “Thin provisioning” and choosing “Flat” file but have not been able create a –flat.vmdk file.  Not sure what situation will cause a –flat.vmdk file to get created.

Thanks

Matt Fitzsimmons

Answer (score 4):

Flat files are the actual disk data for a virtual disk, the .vmdk file is really just a pointer to either a flat file or RDM. Don't delete them, that would be bad. If you're interested open up a .vmdk file with a text editor.

Comment: I did notice that in the datastore browser that only certain VMs have the -flat.vmdk file as well as the <name>.vmdk which is the descriptor file.  All of the VMs that I have created today do not have the -flat.vmdk They just have a <name>.vmdk that is the actual virtual disk.

Comment: by default the flat files are hidden.

Comment: Ahh, that makes since.  So the .vmdk file that I see in the datastore browser is acutally the descriptor file.  Any reason some would not be hidden?

Comment: someone been using ssh or scripts? I suspect general 'messing around' :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe only thick-provisioned VMs will have '-flat' files.

Comment: Not on my ESX(i) 4.1 system, thin provisioned disks get a -flat too.

Comment: agreed, it's RDMs that don't have -thin's